# Count tr in tbody, which have a certain style trait

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've trying to count the number of `td`'s in a `tbody`, which have a `white background-color`. I need to update the text of a `span` after my count. The class of my `span` is `.attendenceCount`

```
$(".attendenceCount").closest('tbody')...
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Søløve 16:50-17:30 (3017) <span style="color:black;" class="attendenceCounter">tmp</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style='background-color:white;'>
            <td>Albert Hvistendahl Fabel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:green;'>
            <td>Albert Hvistendahl Fabel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:white;'>
            <td>Albert Hvistendahl Fabel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:green;'>
            <td>Alma Valbjørn Bratved</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:white;'>
            <td>Albert Hvistendahl Fabel</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How would this be possible?

Comment: Is the background colour defined inline as in "bgcolor", or via CSS? is it "white" "White" or "ffffff"?

Comment: It is defined as 'White' via CSS

Comment: Showing your HTML would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer now you've quoted your HTML**:

Now that you've quoted your HTML, you're showing it as:

```
<tr style='background-color:white;'>
    <td>Albert Hvistendahl Fabel</td>
</tr>
```

If the `style` attribute will **really** look *exactly* like that, there is a shortcut:

```
var tds = $(".attendenceCount").closest('tbody').find('tr[style="background-color:white;"] td');
```

...but if you change the `style` attribute *at all* (adding a space between `background-color:` and `white`, for instance), that will stop working.

**The main recommendation** really has to be to change the HTML so you have something easier to look for, like a class.

---

**Original answer**:

There's no shortcut, you have to find all the `td` elements and loop through them checking if they have a white `background-color` (probably via `filter`). Beware that the `element.style.backgroundColor` (or `$element.css("background-color")` may be in hex or rgb notation, so you have to allow for that.

*Something* like:

```
var whiteBackgroundTds =
    $(".attendenceCount").closest('tbody').find('td').filter(onlyWhiteBG);

function onlyWhiteBG() {
    var bgcolor = (this.style.backgroundColor || "").toLowerCase(),
        m,
        isWhite = false;

    if (bgcolor.substring(0, 3) === "rgb") {
        // Handle rgb or rgba (check this rex, it's off-the-cuff
        m = /\s*rgb(?:a)?\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)/;
        if (m && m[1] === "255" && m[2] === "255" && m[3] === "255") {
            isWhite = true;
        }
    }
    else switch (bgcolor) {
        case "white": // Not likely
        case "#ffffff":
        case "#fff":
            isWhite = true;
    }
    return false; // Not white
}
```

...but that's nearly pseudocode. The idea is just to point you in the right direction.

Note that this will only match `td` elements *specifically* assigned the `background-color`. If you need to find ones where that's assigned via a style, use `$(this).css("background-color")` instead of `this.style.backgroundColor` above.

Comment: +1 - after multiple attempts to filter elements based on colors, it has to be the worst css property to match ever, as it can be hex, rgb, rgba, and newer browsers might even use hsl in the future, so it's really not worth doing when it's so easy to add a class or something instead.

Comment: @adeneo: HSL -- yikes, please tell me browsers won't start giving us that... :-)

Comment: They probably will at some time, most now support RGBA, and isn't HSL and HSV the new great way to represent RGB values, at least until something new and more shiny comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example I made](http://jsfiddle.net/2JFPP/) on jsfiddle. It uses the rgb for the colors, because I use chrome, and you might need to change that (look at T.J.Crowder's answer regarding that).

```
function calc_attendence() {
    var count = 0,
        tds = $('tbody td');

    $.each(tds, function (index, value) {
        var color = $(value).css('background-color');
        if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') { //works for me because I'm using chrome
            count = count + 1
        }
    });

    return count
};
```

Comment: That is *very* fragile. It'll break even in other browsers that use `rgb` (because some don't include the spaces).

Comment: That's right. I only meant to convey the general idea and I mentioned in the answer that the color part is problematic